# Background-position não está funcionando

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, background-image

Olá, pessoal. Utilizei a técnica do image-replacement, tentei deixar a imagem centralizada usando o background-position: center center, mas a posição da imagem permanece inalterada.  Alguém saberia dizer por quê o background-position não está funcionando, como eu posso arrumar isso? Segue o print:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
aside {
  height: 100vw;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-right: 3px solid #000;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px !important;
}

aside h1 {
    background-image: url(cal.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 208px;
    width: 200px;
}

aside h1 span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
   
   <div class="columns">
      
       <aside class="column is-3">
           <h1><span>Lorem ipsum</span></h1>
           
       </aside>
                   
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se bem é isso, mas  width: 200px está dando conflito,

```css
aside {
  height: 100vw;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-right: 3px solid #000;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px !important;
}

aside h1 {
     
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mdGL.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 208px;
   
}

aside h1 span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
   
   <div class="columns">
      
       <aside class="column is-3">
           <h1><span>Lorem ipsum</span></h1>
           
       </aside>
                   
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi bem simples como estavas a rendimensionar a imagem o width estava a dar conflito então basta adicionares:

```
aside h1{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```css
aside {
  height: 100vw;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-right: 3px solid #000;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px !important;
}

aside h1 {
    background-image: url("https://image.prntscr.com/image/RQ2u88wpQDmxnJNQyput-Q.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 208px;
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

aside h1 span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
    <aside class="column is-3">
        <h1><span>Lorem ipsum</span></h1>
           
    </aside>
</div>
```